Setting up path to find packages and modules
I have the follwing folder structure of my Python project:
Project is the base directory.
Project     
  |------package1
  |          |--------module1.py
  |          |--------module2.py 
  |------package2
  |          |--------module3.py
  |          |--------module4.py 
  |------Test
  |        |-----test.py

The contents of test.py is:
import package1.module1

When I run test.py, the below error is thrown:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'

I am aware that the package/module search would contain the directory where the script is run.
So in this case, package1 directory path is NOT included; hence the error is thrown.
Adding the path of package1 via sys.path.append() is not a nicer way whenever we do imports.
I see that many projects import modules/packages in the above mentioned way only.
I am wondering how they work actually.
can I get some guidance on how to make the above setup work.
Thanks

I think that you need __init__.py files in all of the directories (including the top-level directory). Then, if you rename the top-level directory to project, use the code
import project.package1.model1

I tried the approach that you suggested. but somehow it is not working.
